# Compress a damaged-disk with lots of duplicate files dd image for archival

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, backup, compression

Here is the description of the problem: I'm trying to compress the best way I know a before-recovery disk image so that if my client data is ruined by the recovery they can go back to the original disk-image and try to extract the damaged data directly from the dd image.

Now some info about the disk itself: it's a 1TB SSD with 2 partitions, one with the OS and most data and another one with two huge almost duplicate folders coming from 2 different file recovery programs (they seem to be a master of destroying hard disks). So in the disk image the are for sure lots of duplicates among the first and the second partition and in the second partition there are for sure almost only duplicates. One example of duplicates files could be: the first copy in the first GBs of the first partition, the second at the start of the second partition and the third duplicate at the end of the second partition.

That said: is there any software that can properly remove such long distance redundancies (might even be more than 500GB afar from each other) before compressing the file itself?

I've tried the only software that apparently claims to do so, **lrzip** with  its `-U` option and effectively using its `-n` option that apparently doesn't apply any more action than the redundancy removal step I only obtain a reduction from 1TB to ~730GBs, it took 67h on 16GB RAM i7 system which seems great but also sort of lackluster considering the amount of duplicate data I noticed in the recovered partitions on the new SSD.

Have I been using **lrzip** correctly? Is there any way to do it faster? Does it really remove all the duplicate data even at hundreds of GBs of distance? Is there any other software capable of such long distance data redundancy removal? Does **zstd**'s `--long` option remove any such long distance redundancy? Is the difference in disk space usage going to be so amazing that I really shouldn't save time and compress the disk image with **zstd** or **lz4**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"duplicate folders coming from 2 different file recovery programs"* whoever set a recovery app to recover to the same drive they were recovering from has probably killed all hope. You should only be working on a dd image anyway & not touching the original drive at all unless the fail is mechanical, in which case you need more than recovery software.

Comment: How much do you cost per hour? The pragmatic approach (and may be even cheaper unless your time is totally free of cost) would be to by two different 1TB drives and store the image in uncompressed from on both of them. Why uncompressed? Because if you really need to access it later for e.g. an 10KB file uncompressing 1TB before you can access the file costs a lot of time.

Comment: @Tetsujin it was data recovered from a previous hard disk drive. But this time they luckily gave the SSD directly to me so that I could firstly save an untouched disk-image and then repair the partition table and partition headers to recover all the data, first to another volume for them to check and then in place on the SSD itself once they gave me their consent

Comment: @Robert unluckily it's not a paid work, it's actually a friend of my father who f'ed up with its old pc a few hundred times already. It's actually more of an experiment on my side that I left running on my home pc for days

Comment: If the data is recovered why do you need to fix the disk [again]? Why not just erase & copy back? & as @Robert says, why go to all the trouble of compressing it all for the sake of 1TB? Just use another drive. Comping/uncomping is going to take days for a few hundred GB of 'saved' space. It makes no practical sense, let alone economical.

Comment: Get a good 1TB+ disk, put ZFS on it, enable deduplication and gzip9 compression, create a 1TB zvol without space reservation, and dd the broken disk image onto that.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah, Robert is for sure right, and I'm also pretty sure the guy's not even that aware that a data-recovery retrieval could be done at all. The reason why I started this experiment is that being this data recovery effort for free as the guy is a friend of my father I don't really want to put any effort - or money, not even for a "cheap" 1 TB hdd, more than writing some commands on a command line and letting the pc run its magic. The objective of the experiment was to get a small enough disk image to make it fit onto the free space of one of the recovered partitions.

Comment: @GordanBobić can I ask you what a zvol is? I only know it's an emulation of a block device. Could I then save or export that zvol as an already compressed file? Thanks in advance

Comment: @gio91ber zvol is a volume (block device) on top of a ZFS pool. You could "zfs send -Dcp" and pipe it to a file, and the stream would preserve the properties and be deduplicated. Caveats: 1) zfs send -D feature only works on ZFS < 2.x, latest of which is 0.8.6. 2) The generated send stream will not be restorable if any of it is corrupted. I byte of corruption, and receive will abort.